# Using ESP-IDF to recieve UDP packets via ethernet

Tags: udp, esp32, ethernet, esp-idf

I want to use the ESP-IDF framework to make a program that will recieve UDP packets via ethernet. I am not using an ESP32-Ethernet-Kit, but an ESP32 alongside a PHY (DP83848) in order to gain access to ethernet.

Pretty much every example I can find about UDP and ESP32 is using Wifi instead of ethernet.

What I want to do is use the [basic ethernet example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/ethernet/basic) available in the espressif esp-idf git repository as a starting point and then add the functionality to recieve the datagrams.
If I'm not wrong, what I should do is create a new event handler and use the esp_eth_update_input_path API present in the [esp_eth_driver.h](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp_eth/include/esp_eth_driver.h), but I am not sure about how to use it. Can anyone help me with this?

```
esp_err_t esp_eth_update_input_path(
    esp_eth_handle_t hdl,
    esp_err_t (*stack_input)(esp_eth_handle_t hdl, uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t length, void *priv),
    void *priv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted almost the same question in the espressif ESP-IDF forum before posting this one here and got an following answer by user **ESP_ondrej**.
I'm posting it here in case this can help someone.

> All protocols examples located in the ESP-IDF supports both Wifi and
> Ethernet. You just need to configure it via `idf.py menuconfig`.
> Please check the README at https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/bl ...
> /README.md
>
> If you want to start from scratch with your Ethernet UDP application,
> you can do so. You don't need to call `esp_eth_update_input_path`.
> This function is used to direct L2 Ethernet frames to specific
> callback function which you don't want since you want to communicate
> via IP protocol. Therefore keep it as is, i.e. Ethernet frames are to
> be processed by lwIP stack and just use socket API as you might be
> used to from other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I have an [ESP32-Ethernet-Kit](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/hw-reference/esp32/get-started-ethernet-kit.html) V1.2 board.

For Ethernet, it has an IP101GRI chip installed. I used the ESP-IDF [eth_basic example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/ethernet/basic) as a basis for configuring Ethernet and removed the code for other chips. This board also has WiFi.

Working with UDP is not directly related to Ethernet or WiFi, as I understand it. When a packet arrives, it is processed by a socket, regardless of whether it came through a cable or wirelessly. I have confirmed this. You will receive the sender's address (`struct sockaddr_in source_addr;`) and can reply to it. If the response needs to be sent later, simply save the address in another variable and use it when you are ready to send the data.

Some settings:

- IP=192.168.4.1
- Mask=255.255.255.0
- Gateway=192.168.4.1
- port for incoming UDP 33000 (`#define SELF_UDP_PORT 33000`)

I also configured ESP32 as a DHCP-server. I haven't figured out how to set up the DHCP address pool.

In the example, all messages are printed to the console, but if a message "Hi" is received, the response will be "Hello," and if the character "2" is received, the response will be "5." Working with text is just for demonstration and clarity, you can send any data.

Add udp.c and udp.h to your project, don't forget about CMakeLists.txt.

I use esp-idf-v4.4.2 width VS Code.

If you configure WiFi, then udp will work with it, without additional changes in udp.c

file udp.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_UDP_H_
#define MAIN_UDP_H_

#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_log.h"

#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "lwip/sockets.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include <lwip/netdb.h>

void IRAM_ATTR udp_ap_task(void *pvParameters);
void UDPSend(int sockfd, char* buf,int size, struct sockaddr_in* pAddr);

#endif /* MAIN_UDP_H_ */
```

file udp.c:

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOSConfig.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/portmacro.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "udp.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"

#define SELF_UDP_PORT 33000
static const char *TAG_AP = "udp_ap";

#define SIZE_UDPBUF 1460
char udpBuf[SIZE_UDPBUF]={0,};
char* p_udpBuf=0;
int ap_sockfd=-1;
struct sockaddr_in  self_ap_addr;//, gateway, netmask;
int MsgCntr=0;//debug

void IRAM_ATTR udp_ap_task(void *pvParameters) {
  struct sockaddr_in source_addr;
  socklen_t source_addr_len;
  while(1) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG_AP, "Create AP UDP socket...\n");
    if ( (ap_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP)) < 0 ) {
      ESP_LOGE(TAG_AP, "UDP socket not created\n");
      break;
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG_AP, "AP UDP socket created");
    
    self_ap_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    self_ap_addr.sin_port = htons(SELF_UDP_PORT);
    
    if (bind(ap_sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&self_ap_addr,  sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0 ) {
      ESP_LOGI(TAG_AP,"AP UDP socket not binded");
      shutdown(ap_sockfd, 0);
      close(ap_sockfd);
      break;
    }
    char addr_str[16]={0,};
    ESP_LOGI(TAG_AP,"AP UDP socket binded");
    while(1) {
        p_udpBuf=udpBuf;
        source_addr_len=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        ssize_t size=recvfrom(ap_sockfd, udpBuf, sizeof(udpBuf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&source_addr,&source_addr_len);
        if (size<0) break;
        if (size==0) continue;
        MsgCntr++;//debug
        if(size<SIZE_UDPBUF){
            udpBuf[size]=0;//NULL terminator if use udpBuf as string for printf
        }

        printf("Message received: %d, Size=%d, Text:%s\n",MsgCntr, size, udpBuf);
        printf("Port: %d Addr: %s\n",htons(source_addr.sin_port),esp_ip4addr_ntoa((esp_ip4_addr_t*)&source_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,addr_str,sizeof(addr_str)-1));

        if (strcmp(udpBuf,"Hi") == 0){
            sprintf(udpBuf, "%s", "Hello"); 
            UDPSend(ap_sockfd,udpBuf,strlen(udpBuf),&source_addr);
        }
        if(udpBuf[0]=='2'){
            udpBuf[0]='5';
            UDPSend(ap_sockfd,udpBuf,strlen(udpBuf),&source_addr);
        }

    }
    if (ap_sockfd != -1) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG_AP, "Shutting down AP socket and restarting...");
        shutdown(ap_sockfd, 0);
        close(ap_sockfd);
    }
  }
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void UDPSend(int sockfd, char* buf,int size, struct sockaddr_in* pAddr) {
  if (sockfd<0) return;
  sendto(sockfd, buf, size, 0,(struct sockaddr*)pAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
}
```

file main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_eth.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "./sdkconfig.h"
#if CONFIG_ETH_USE_SPI_ETHERNET
#include "driver/spi_master.h"
#endif // CONFIG_ETH_USE_SPI_ETHERNET

#include "udp.h"

static const char *TAG = "eth_example";

#include <esp_netif.h>
#include <esp_eth.h>

esp_netif_t *eth_netif=0;
esp_eth_handle_t eth_handle = NULL;

//Event handler for Ethernet events 
static void eth_event_handler(void *arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                              int32_t event_id, void *event_data)
{
    uint8_t mac_addr[6] = {0};
    //we can get the ethernet driver handle from event data
    esp_eth_handle_t eth_handle = *(esp_eth_handle_t *)event_data;

    switch (event_id) {
    case ETHERNET_EVENT_CONNECTED:
        esp_eth_ioctl(eth_handle, ETH_CMD_G_MAC_ADDR, mac_addr);
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ethernet Link Up");
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ethernet HW Addr %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
                 mac_addr[0], mac_addr[1], mac_addr[2], mac_addr[3], mac_addr[4], mac_addr[5]);
        break;
    case ETHERNET_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ethernet Link Down");
        break;
    case ETHERNET_EVENT_START:
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ethernet Started");
        break;
    case ETHERNET_EVENT_STOP:
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ethernet Stopped");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

//Event handler for IP_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP
static void got_ip_event_handler(void *arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                                 int32_t event_id, void *event_data)
{
    ip_event_got_ip_t *event = (ip_event_got_ip_t *) event_data;
    const esp_netif_ip_info_t *ip_info = &event->ip_info;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ethernet Got IP Address");
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "~~~~~~~~~~~");
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ETHIP:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&ip_info->ip));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ETHMASK:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&ip_info->netmask));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ETHGW:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&ip_info->gw));
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "~~~~~~~~~~~");

    esp_netif_dns_info_t dns_info;
    esp_netif_get_dns_info(eth_netif, ESP_NETIF_DNS_MAIN, &dns_info);

    char dns_str[16];
    sprintf(dns_str, IPSTR, IP2STR(&dns_info.ip.u_addr.ip4));

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "DNS Server: %s", dns_str);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "~~~~~~~~~~~");

}

void setupEthernet() {
    // Create new default instance of esp-netif for Ethernet
    esp_netif_config_t cfg = ESP_NETIF_DEFAULT_ETH();
    eth_netif = esp_netif_new(&cfg);

    //static IP
    esp_netif_dhcpc_stop(eth_netif);

    esp_netif_ip_info_t ip_info;
    IP4_ADDR(&ip_info.ip, 192, 168, 4, 1);
    IP4_ADDR(&ip_info.gw, 192, 168, 4, 1);
    IP4_ADDR(&ip_info.netmask, 255, 255, 255, 0);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_set_ip_info(eth_netif, &ip_info));

    // Init MAC and PHY configs to default
    eth_mac_config_t mac_config = ETH_MAC_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
    eth_phy_config_t phy_config = ETH_PHY_DEFAULT_CONFIG();

    phy_config.phy_addr = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_ADDR;//1
    phy_config.reset_gpio_num = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_PHY_RST_GPIO;//5
    mac_config.smi_mdc_gpio_num = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_MDC_GPIO;//23
    mac_config.smi_mdio_gpio_num = CONFIG_EXAMPLE_ETH_MDIO_GPIO;//18
    esp_eth_mac_t *mac = esp_eth_mac_new_esp32(&mac_config);

    esp_eth_phy_t *phy = esp_eth_phy_new_ip101(&phy_config);

    esp_eth_config_t config = ETH_DEFAULT_CONFIG(mac, phy);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_eth_driver_install(&config, &eth_handle));// Init Ethernet
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_attach(eth_netif, esp_eth_new_netif_glue(eth_handle)));//attach Ethernet driver to TCP/IP stack


    // Register user defined event handers
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(ETH_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &eth_event_handler, NULL));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP, &got_ip_event_handler, NULL));

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_eth_start(eth_handle));//start Ethernet driver state machine

    //DHCP
    esp_netif_dhcp_status_t DHCPStatus;
    esp_netif_dhcps_get_status(eth_netif,&DHCPStatus);
    //ESP_LOGW(TAG_STA,"DHCP srv status: %d",DHCPStatus);
    if (DHCPStatus!=ESP_NETIF_DHCP_STOPPED){// Stop dhcp server
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_dhcps_stop(eth_netif));
    }
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_dhcps_start(eth_netif));// Start dhcp server

}

void app_main() {
    // Initialize TCP/IP network interface (should be called only once in application)
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    // Create default event loop that running in background
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

    setupEthernet();// setup Ethernet and make netif

    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(udp_ap_task,"udp_ap_task", 4096, NULL, 5, NULL, 1);
}
```